# How to re-do a code part if there is an error without rewriting it ?

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

In my code I make some API calls and sometimes 1 of them return an error but if I re-do it just after it works (I don't really know what's wrong maybe the JSON that I post is not finish or I don't know...)

So to make that I have coded:

```
 HTTP.call("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db", {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': APIKEY,
                    },
                    data: {
                        dashboard: dataJSON,
                        overwrite: true
                    }
                },
                function(error, result) {
                    if (!error) {
                        console.error("result post dataJSON --------------------OK------------")
                    } else {
                        console.log("error post dataJSON  --------------------KO------------")


                        HTTP.call("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db", {
                                headers: {
                                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                    'Authorization': APIKEY,
                                },
                                data: {
                                    dashboard: dataJSON,
                                    overwrite: true
                                }
                            },
                            function(error, result) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    console.error("result post dataJSON at the 2nd time --------------------OK------------")
                                } else {
                                    console.log("error post dataJSON  at the 2nd time --------------------KO------------")
                                }
                            });
                    }
```

But it's very ugly to make something like this I think so is it a way to recall the code's part when there is an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my first suggestion is to understand why the call fails the first time around and see if you can fix it.

Excluding that, it depends a bit on you plan to use the data and such, but, for example, you could isolate the HTTP call in a function, and recall the function with the same arguments.

```
function callAPIwithData(myData) {

    HTTP.call("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db", {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': APIKEY,
        },
        data: myData
    },
    function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
            console.error("OK: result post dataJSON")
        } else {
            console.log("KO: error post dataJSON")
            console.log("retrying ...")
            callAPIWithData(myData);
        }
    });

}
```

of course this will need a set of checks and balances so it won't get stuck re-trying to infinity in casa there's something else broken, but you get the idea.

Comment: YES It's a very great idea !

Comment: If you are interested I have set a var `limit` and I just use a `if` to avoid infinity re-trying